# Persist data in cron folders on Openshift

Tags: python, git, cron, openshift

I want to create shell scripts files programmatically and place them in openshift cron directorys.

With this code I can place them in minutely folder:

```
import os
path = os.environ['CUSTOM_CRON_MINUTELY']
f = open(path+'/my_shell_script.sh', 'w+')
f.write("....")
```

And then the result looks good

```
.openshift
|-- action_hooks
|   `-- README.md
|-- cron
|   |-- daily
|   |-- hourly
|   |-- minutely
|   |   `-- my_shell_script.sh
|   |-- monthly
|   |-- README.cron
|   `-- weekly
|       |-- chrono.dat
|       |-- chronograph
|       |-- jobs.allow
|       |-- jobs.deny
|       `-- README
|-- markers
|   `-- README.md
`-- README.md
```

But everytime I make a git push the repository is reset and my_shell_script.sh is deleted. Is there anyway to avoid this behavior to persist files in cron folders? any workarround is welcome.

Answer (score 2):

Create them in the openshift Data directory that will always persist. When you push have your code copy the cron scripts from there to your desired cron folder.

Comment: You mean, create the script twice, right? I was thinking to make a pull of openshift repo.

Comment: To persist through "pushes" the dynamically created script would have to live in the Data directory. Yes, the scripts would be on the server twice. Your code would have to copy them into the cron folders when your code starts after the push.  As you stated, you could do a pull first every time you make a change. Don't forget, or will loose everything.

Comment: Yep, that's my first option, but today i figure out maybe I can create a new folder in openshift repo and  then ignore it.

Comment: Hmm. I never tried that way. Let me know if that works.

Answer (score 0):

Put into each of cron folders ("minutely" etc) a single script that runs (in parallel? background?) all scripts from ~/app-root/data folder. Then your dynamic scripts will be there only in one place, and won't get overwritten. Mind however that the data folder does not get copied when the app is scaled, contrary to the cron folders.